# Why is my table rendering in a nonsensical place?

Tags: tables

I'm using TexWorks and am trying to use the following table:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\( a+b=b+a \) & \( a \cdot b = b \cdot a \)   \\
a & a  \\
a & a 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The table renders in the beginning of the text for unknown reasons. See:

> [image]

Perhaps it's a consequence of the header of my code? It is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
```

I didn't forget the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. I just ommited it.

Comment: Use `\begin{table}[htb]`

Comment: or `\begin{table}[h]`

Comment: For the full explanation see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020). For the solution, do what @HarishKumar said.  See also [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275).

Comment: When you add a title, this shouldn't happen. At least, not with standard classes and settings. Presumably you'll have a title in the end, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If you don't want or need a caption for that one, use `\begin{center}\begin{tabular}....\end{tabular}\end{center}` instead.